# Is it possible to send an aspx page in email body?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, c#-4.0, smtp

```
<div class="popup-holder">
            <div class="popup-frame">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="mail-block">
                        <div class="mail-holder">
                            <strong class="mail-logo"><a href="#">abc website</a></strong>
                            <div class="mail-page">
                                <div class="mail-page-holder">
                                    <div class="mail-page-frame">
                                        <p>Hello &lt;<asp:Label ID="lblfriend" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>>!,</p>
                                        <p>Great News!  &lt;One of your FB Friends/<asp:Label ID="lblmyname" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>>  has invited you to BlissLink.</p>
                                        <p>(<asp:Label ID="lblmyname1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>) says:  &lt;<asp:Label
                                            ID="lblmess" runat="server" Text="abc is fun ,"></asp:Label>><br /><br /></p>
                                        <p></p>
                                        <ul class="f-list">
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span> 
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image6" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span> <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span> <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image9" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span><asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span> <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span><asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <asp:Image ID="Image12" runat="server" width="48" height="48" />
                                                <strong class="title"><span><asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" ></asp:Label></span></strong>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Expand Your Network"  CssClass="btn" />
                                        <span class="bot-text">Cheers,<br />Your abc Team</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="un">If you have no more interest in receiving our news, <a href="#">unsubscribe.</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

these images are decided at runtime is there anyway of embedding it in the email body

please help

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. How would an ASPX page in an email ( as an attachment ) even be able to reference anything without absolute URLs to assets?

Comment: I don't think so it is possible and a good thing to email aspx page, how about using a [Template Engine](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) to change src of images while sending html of page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want that part of the markup in the email, then put it inside a user control (myEmailControl.ascx). You can then call Render() on the control from the script that sends the email and intercept the html output of the control. Then you can put that html into an email body. (Your images will also need absolute urls so that they show up in the email, but I'm sure you've already thought of that)

Page/Handler that sends the email:

```
    StringBuilder htmlResponse = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(htmlResponse))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            Control emailBody = Page.LoadControl("myEmailControl.ascx");
            emailBody.RenderControl(textWriter);
        }
    }
    string emailHtml = htmlResponse.ToString();
```

Comment: yup i tried that but i am not getting values in the Labels how do i do that?

Comment: Have you tried adding the control to a regular aspx page and checking the rendered output? You get the same output if the control is on a page or rendered by the RenderControl method, but it's easier to step through the code when the control is on a page.

If it still doesn't work, please post the code you are using to populate the label values.

Answer (score 4):

You could download the rendered HTML from the page and send that:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://server.com/path/to/page.aspx");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

StringReader reader = new StringReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Now you can just send the contents of `html` in your email.

Comment: I tried this code, I am not able to see the images in mail body. It's returning plain text.@Kyle did you try it at ur end ?

Comment: @Pankaj No, I didn't test this.  You're getting plain text, because that is exactly what html is.  Can you post the code you are using to send the email?  Make sure you enable html in your message.

Comment: @PeekaySwitch that depends on whether the images are being rendered with absolute or relative paths.  That's another problem/question however.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: - I had to modify it a bit. **FYI - WebRequest class can not be instantiated like this.**

Comment: @Pankaj Its been a while since I used it.  Fixed to use `.Create()`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to output the images as a Base 64 in the HTML.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBrkJggg==" alt="Base 64 encoded!" />
```

In your code behind, get the image, convert it to a Base 64 and print that as the src instead!